# Render a form that shows list values as the checkbox values. [each entry in the list represent a checkbox field]

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Is it possible to render a form from a list data?

For example let

```
Cont = ['Brazil' ,'India', 'USA', 'Aus', 'UAE', 'Russia', 'China']
```

I want to present a form to user that shows the entries in the form as checkbox which I can save into a result list called `Result= []`.

How is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at the Form widget CheckBoxSelectMultiple: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`MultipleChoiceField`** form field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) with as widget a [**`CheckboxSelectMultiple`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple):

```
from django import forms

COUNTRIES = ['Brazil', 'India', 'USA', 'Aus', 'UAE', 'Russia', 'China']

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(c, c) for c in COUNTRIES],
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

If you submit the POST data to the `MyForm` instance, and validate it, the cleaned data will contain as `countries` the values selected.

Comment: thanks man. that worked. I have another that just came up. ```Countries``` list is supposed to a list out from the last form result. Is there any method to get the lists into this one? let's say I want to process ```MyForm``` and get the result in a list and use that list in another ```MyForm2```. How can that be possible?